# couldn't break line in email body

Tags: php, html

I cant break new lines for email body. i have used \n but im gettting "\n" in result intead of new line

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (isset($_POST['btn_star_subscribe']))
    {
        $to = "asif.yoosuf@live.com";
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = 'Name:'.$_POST['name'].'/n'.'Mobile:'.$_POST['phone'].'\n'.'Message:'.$_POST['message'];
        $header = 'From:'.$_POST['email'];
        $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        if( $retval == true )  
        {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' id='success-alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button> <strong>Your request has been sent to our company, They will Contact to shortly</strong> </div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' id='success-alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button> <strong>Error Sending, Please check your email</strong></div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` to wrap your `\n`. Using `'` treats the `\` as a literal (not an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)).

```
$message = 'Name:'.$_POST['name']."\n".'Mobile:'.$_POST['phone']."\n".'Message:'.$_POST['message'];
```

Comment: its wrking :) thnk u, my upvote wont work until i get 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

use \n in double quote not in single quote
then it will work well

Comment: its wrking :) thnk u, my upvote wont work until i get 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using "\n\r" instead of "\n"

Comment: its wrking :) thnk u, my upvote wont work until i get 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
<?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            if (isset($_POST['btn_star_subscribe']))
            {
                $to = "asif.yoosuf@live.com";
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = 'Name:'.$_POST['name']."<br />";
                $message .= 'Mobile:'.$_POST['phone']."<br />";
                $message .= 'Message:'.$_POST['message']."<br />";
                $header = 'From:'.$_POST['email'];
                $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
               if( $retval == true )  
                           {

                              echo "<div class='alert alert-success' id='success-alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button> <strong>Your request has been sent to our company, They will Contact to shortly</strong> </div>";
                           }
                            else
                           {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' id='success-alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button> <strong>Error Sending, Please check your email</strong></div>";
                           }
            }
        }
```

Comment: oops, my mistake in tension all answers are working :) thank u,

Comment: i did already but im new to SOF so i need min 15 reputation for upvote :) its shoring a  message as i cant upvote.